# How do I copy contents of stack to a queue and back from queue to stack in c#?

Tags: c#, stack, queue

So I have this stack and I'm not sure how to copy it's contents to a queue and then back vice versa (when copied back from queue to stack the values would be backwards?)

```
Stack st = new Stack();

st.Push('E');
st.Push('L');
st.Push('P');
st.Push('M');
st.Push('A');
st.Push('X');
st.Push('E');
```

Answer (score 3):

`Stack` implements `ICollection` so you can use [the constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4k9ycya%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Queue` that takes an `ICollection`:

```
Queue queue = new Queue(st);
```

Likewise for Stack:

```
Stack st2 = new Stack(queue);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I know this is a fairly simple question but I couldn't find anything helpful